# Datatable search box doesn't working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable

i have fetch data from mysql using datatable. datatable displayed data but when i search any data from search box. it's show a warning message.
[image: My image is here]

here is my model code.

```
$this->db->from($this->table);
    $i=0;//for search box.

    foreach ($this->column_search as $item)//take column_search item in the loop check request and provide result. 
    {
        if($_POST['search']['value'])//search box take request value if it's POST request
        {
            if($i===0) // first loop. if when i is equal and identical
            {
                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }

            if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        } 
        $i++;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    } 
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
```

Comment: what's the error in your console log?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). that's show in console error

Comment: well ? it's self explanatory now

Answer (score 0):

it could be missing column, check the result data